# Get href from <a> in <li>

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I try to get the correct href from an element  :

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm center">
    <li class="prev disabled">
        <span> … </span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <span> … </span>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a href="/patients/79799?_=1386477592765&page=2" rel="next"> … </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try to get the fref from the a tag thats parent is li class next:

```
$.getScript($('.pagination .next').attr('href'))
```

I get some output but somehow it never shows the `page` params! For eg my code triggers:

```
[06:00:16.759] GET http://localhost:3000/patients/79799?_=1386477659392 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK  672ms]
```

Is there another, better way to get the url without any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The href is specified in the anchor element within `.next` element, so you need to find the anchor element first

```
('.pagination .next a').attr('href')
```